# How to give the focus to the text field?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, focus, alert

Very simple setting: I have a ViewController scene with a TextField on it. The ViewController is the text field's delegate.

I would like to have the following behavior: When the user enters the text field (i.e., taps on it), I would like to display a modal alert box with an OK button. After the users presses OK, the TextField should get the focus (i.e., cursor blinking inside it).

I can't get this working. I react on the user tapping in the text field by `textFieldShouldBeginEditing()`. This works in the sense that I can display the message box there. But after the user (in this case it's me ;o)) taps the OK button, the text field doesn't have the focus, and when I tap it again, the message box appears again.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: If you show an alert each time the text field gains focus then putting the focus back in the text field after dismissing the alert will cause the alert to appear again. Why are you showing an alert when the user puts the focus on the text field? Then why put the focus back? What are you trying to achieve? And show relevant code in your question.

Comment: This is a minimal example. In the end, I would like to ask the user whether they want to paste stuff from the clipboard when they enter/tap the text field. That's why. And why should I display code? Ii's not so hard to imagine a text field in a view controller, is it? That's basically all I have...

Comment: Why prompt them? The user can tap on the text field a second time to bring up the menu and they can then tap Paste from the menu if they wish.

Comment: @maddy Actually, you are right. Thank you. I'll not implement this. What a stupid idea... However, I am interested in how this could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *really* want the modal dialog to show *every* time the text field is clicked? Bear in mind that putting the activation in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing()` will mean that re-activating the field after dismissing the dialog will re-show the dialog.

Maybe you just need to show the dialog once? In which case a simple boolean flag that is set on first showing will fix the issue. I.e. at view controller scope:

```
var hasShownWarningDialog = false
```

and then implement instead (after comments):

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
  if !hasShownWarningDialog
  {
    hasShownWarningDialog = true
    // Create dialog here
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()})
    return false
  }
  else
  {
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks. But however, it doesn't work properly because after the dialog vanishes, the text view doesn't have the control although I call `becomeFirstResponder`. What I do is the standard: first set up a `UIAlertController` and then display it with `self.present()`. Right after that I call the `becomeFirstResponder´ method. It doesn't work. I have to tap on the edit again.

Comment: You'll need to call `becomeFirstResponder` *after* the dialog has been dismissed, not after it has been shown. Will show in answer.

Comment: Thank you! Now, the only thing left that's annoying is the keyboard that pops up for a very short time after tapping on the edit until the dialog box occurs. Can I avoid this somehow?

Comment: You could try using the other delegate function `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` which means you can disallow editing (by returning false on first call), and show the dialog. If not the first time, just return true instead. I've never used it, but will update answer to demonstrate.